# Paint canvas undo feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

These are the button functions:

```
$("#undo").click(function() {
    Stack1.undo();
});

$("#redo").click(function() {
  Stack1.redo();
});
```

This is the undo function:

```
    function clearCanvas()
    {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

    }
   Stack1 = new Stack();
    ///////////////////

    function Stack(firstImg , size) {
    var drawStack = new Array();
    var stackIndex = 0;
    var stackTop = 0;
    var stackFloor = 0;
    var stackSize = size; 

    drawStack[0] = firstImg;

this.add = function() {
    drawStack[++stackIndex%stackSize] = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    if (stackIndex >= stackSize) stackFloor = (stackIndex +1) % stackSize ;
    stackTop = stackIndex % stackSize;
}

this.undo = function () {
    if (stackIndex%stackSize == stackFloor ) return;
    clearCanvas();
    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.src = drawStack[--stackIndex%stackSize];
    ctx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0);

}

this.redo = function () {
    if (stackIndex%stackSize == stackTop) return;
    clearCanvas();
    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.src = drawStack[++stackIndex%stackSize];
    ctx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0);
}
}
```

Also I declare the array at the top:

```
var drawStack = [];
```

I also put this code before I draw each stroke in my mouse down method:

```
 Stack1.add();
```

Here is my working example..draw 3 circles on screen then click undo, everything goes blank, then click it again and only 2 remain. Its close but I cannot figure out the last part.

Comment: What is the *last part*?

Comment: Why it does not work the way it should. I do not know where its going wrong! :)

Comment: Guess, you have an off by one error on referencing your array.

Answer (score 0):

You've made this more complicated than it needs to be.  The pseudo code for how an undo  function usually works goes:

```
currentState = 0
maxStates = 10
stateArray = []

initialize:
   push the current state onto the top of stateArray 

save:
  if there are states in stateArray above the currentState
    clear the states in stateArray above the current state
  push the current state onto the top of stateArray 
  currentState++
  if the size of stateArray exceeds maxStates
     remove the oldest state from the bottom of stateArray 
     currentState--

undo:
  if there are previous states in stateArray 
    currentState--
    revert the canvas to stateArray[currentState]

redo:
  if there are newer states in stateArray 
     currentState++
     revert the canvas to stateArray[currentState]
```

As you can see:

- You don't ever need the mod operator.
- You don't need to keep track of the top and bottom of the stack, only the index of the current state, the number of states you want and the size of the stateArray.
- You should clear the states in the stateArray above the current state when you add a new one for it to function the way people expect (unless you are going to implement a branching history which most applications do not).

**Edit**: I noticed a different problem in your code, you are trying to immediately draw the image to the canvas instead of waiting for it to load. At minimum your undo function should look like:

```
this.undo = function () {
    if (stackIndex%stackSize == stackFloor) return;
    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.src = drawStack[--stackIndex%stackSize];
    tmpImg.onload = function() {
       clearCanvas();
       ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

If your indexes are right, which I suspect they are not. You can look at an example implementation of the algorithm I described above in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/d4BTx/).

Comment: I have gotten as far as this:  var currentState = 0;
    var maxStates = 10;
     var stateArray = [];
 
var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic";
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
stateArray.push(image);
 
Could you help me with the action function?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a different problem I found and made an example jsFiddle you can take a look at.